# How can I orbit precisely in the 3D viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

I can orbit in the 3D viewport by using the middle mouse button. I can also orbit in fixed increments using <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>8</kbd> on the number pad. But how can I orbit more precisely? For example, I may want to orbit exactly 54.5 degrees on a particular axis.

Comment: Add a camera object and transform with precise rotation values

Comment: .. maybe not your case, but don't forget you can align the view to selected geometry by using Shift with the existing world-alignment shortcuts. e.g. Shift-Numpad-7 will align the view straight down on to a selected face.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I found to do this is to first snap your 3D cursor to the center of the object you want to pivot around, then change your *Transform Pivot Point* to **3D Cursor**. Next, select the object you want your view centered on, and press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to center your view upon that object, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to center the active camera on your current view. Next, turn on *Increment Snapping* and open the settings for it. Under the *Affect* section, Make sure **Rotate** is the only option activated. Now make sure the active camera is currently selected, and press <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd>, and then move the mouse. The view will snap at 5 degree increments. I don't know how to do this any other way, nor how to change the increments of the snapping.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of would be to change the Rotation Angle in user preferences from it's default of 15.0 to 0.5. Doing this changes the rotation increments when you press the 2, 4, 6, 8 keys. I know this is not ideal - if you started straight on by pressing 1, you would literally have to push the 6 key 109 times to rotate 54.5 degrees to the right. A bit time consuming, but at least it's specific. Maybe you could start from a different initial angle and work backwards/forwards to save some steps.

[image: RotationAngle]

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to do this is to create a camera object, change it to be at the exact position and angle you want, and then just use numpad 0 to look from the camera view. You can then delete the camera and your viewport is exactly where you want it.